# python asn1tools - failing compilation of asn.1

Tags: python, asn.1

I'm trying to compile the 3GPP 38.331 ASN.1 specification [here](https://pastebin.com/tDjpj2s0) - which was extracted from the [spec document](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/38_series/38.331/38331-f80.zip)

```
import asn1tools
rrc = asn1tools.compile_files('./data/asn/38331-f80.docx.asn', 'uper')
```

However this throws the error `asn1tools.errors.CompileError: Type 'SetupRelease' not found in module 'NR-RRC-Definitions'.`

I could see the `SetupRelease` definition in the .asn file

```
SetupRelease { ElementTypeParam } ::= CHOICE {
    release         NULL,
    setup           ElementTypeParam
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/eerimoq/asn1tools (if this is the one) 'Parametrization (X.683) is not yet supported' (see my answer for a work around)

Comment: The library referenced is correct. Is there any alternative library that would support `Parametrization (X.683)` ?

Comment: At first glance, the tool you are using is well and alive (so my work around is worth a try). Another python tool is https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1 (I don't know if it supports parameterization)

Comment: @user320644 Try pycrate project - https://github.com/P1sec/pycrate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely your compiler does not support parameterized types.

You can write the specification a different way (keeping it compatible)

Consider removing this from your spec ...

```
SetupRelease { ElementTypeParam } ::= CHOICE {
    release         NULL,
    setup           ElementTypeParam
}
```

Every time this type is referenced in the specification, replace `ElementTypeParam` with the actual type.

For example ...

```
LocationMeasurementIndication-IEs ::=       SEQUENCE {
    measurementIndication                       SetupRelease {LocationMeasurementInfo},
    lateNonCriticalExtension                    OCTET STRING                                                            OPTIONAL,
    nonCriticalExtension                        SEQUENCE{}                                                              OPTIONAL
}
```

Should become

```
LocationMeasurementIndication-IEs ::=       SEQUENCE {
    measurementIndication  CHOICE {
        release         NULL,
        setup           LocationMeasurementInfo
    },
    lateNonCriticalExtension   OCTET STRING   OPTIONAL,
    nonCriticalExtension    SEQUENCE{}        OPTIONAL
}
```